# Check to see if an Outlook TaskList Item already exists

Tags: c#, outlook

I would like to programmatically grab new tasks from a SQL database and add them into my Outlook task list.  There is no problem for me to query all the data I need and add them into the task list in MS-Outlook.  below is my code:

```
 Outlook.TaskItem oTask = outlookApp.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olTaskItem);
            oTask.Subject = "Go do task 1";
            oTask.DueDate = Convert.ToDateTime("03/20/2015");
            oTask.StartDate = Convert.ToDateTime("03/20/2015");
            oTask.Body = "test task body";

            oTask.SchedulePlusPriority = "High";
            oTask.Status = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlTaskStatus.olTaskInProgress;

            oTask.Save();
```

However, I would like to check if the same item (combination of 1 or 2 columns) is already exists in the Outlook task list.  If the taskitem is already there, then don't save it.  Is there any way to do that?

I would really appreciate any help here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this work?  (Source Code modified, thank to Dmitry)

```
   private bool IsTaskItemExists(TaskObject oTaskItem)
            {
                Outlook.NameSpace ns = null;
                Outlook.MAPIFolder tasksFolder = null;
                Outlook.Items taskFolderItems = null;
                Outlook.TaskItem task = null;
                Outlook.Application outlookApp = new Application();
                bool foundItem = false;
                try
                {
                    ns = outlookApp.Session;
                    tasksFolder = ns.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderTasks);
                    taskFolderItems = tasksFolder.Items;

                    foundItem = (taskFolderItems.Find(String.Format("[Property Name]='{0}'", oTaskItem.Property) ) != null);


                    return foundItem;

                }
                finally
                {
                    if (taskFolderItems != null)
                        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(taskFolderItems);
                    if (tasksFolder != null)
                        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(tasksFolder);
                    if (ns != null)
                        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(ns);
                }
            }
```

Comment: Do not ever loop through all items in a folder. This is asking for trouble, In the best case your code will be slow. In the worst case you will run out of RPC channels (in case of online Exchange) and Outlook will raise an exception. Use Items.Find/FindNext/Restrict.

Answer (score 0):

What is the criteria? Open the folder where you create the tasks (Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderTasks), then search using Items.Find/FindNext/Restrict